# Period of Trigonometric Functions

Tags: trigonometry

I have always been taught that in the scenario of a Sine,Tan,Cos function

of $f(x) = a\sin b(x+c) +d$, the period of the sine and cos functions $= \dfrac{2\pi}{b}$, and the period for the tan function $= \dfrac{\pi}{b}$

I don't see how this would apply to trigonometric functions that have powers or trig functions multiplied within the function

e.g $\sin x\tan x + \cos x$...what would be the period?

$\cos^2x\tan x - \sin x$...what would be the period?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.mymathforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=17430

Comment: If one period is a rational multiple of the other then there will be a common period that is the lowest common multiple of the two periods, however if one period is a rational number and the other is irrational then the result is not even periodic as they cannot cycle through integer multiples of their respective periods in any given interval

Answer (score 3):

Any expression comprised of functions that all have the same period $t$ with respect to a certain variable is either constant or has a period which divides $t$.  So for example, $\sin(x)^2$ has period $\pi$ which divides $2 \cdot \pi$, the period of $\sin(x)$.